# Hard Drive read only and one not showing up

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive

So I have 3 different drives: two 250GB drives and one 320GB drive.

However in `Files` only two show up, one called "Computer" (90GB) and one called "files" (250GB which is one of the hard drives) However that's all I get, and when I try to install anything it automatically goes to the 90GB system where my OS is. How do I fix this? I'd love to be able to use all my GB and install stuff in other places than OS :p

Danke

[image: Screenshot of the drives]

Comment: I think you want to mount these drives. If yes, then the problem may be the filesystems. On a 250GB drive, you can create one large 250GB filesystem, or you can create many smaller filesystems. Also, you can only mount properly formatted filesystems (you cannot mount unformatted free space)